# Private Chat App - Parse and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, chat

I want to build a private chat app. My design is only a UITableView for now and I am using Parse (coding in swift).
For now I got the send and receiving part working (with every animation like the text field that grows with the keyboard and all), but I am querying every messages on the class "messages" instead of only the messages sent from user1 to user2... does any of you know how to make a query of only specific object ? what should I do ?

Thanks for your help

PS: I searched a long time before asking that questions and I could not find anything.

Comment: Your message table hopefully has two user fields indicating the tower users taking part in the conversation. (or even an array of users if you have groups). You then use `where` to reduce the amount of matching rows like `findMessages.whereKey("otherUser",  equalTo: conversationPartner)` etc.

Comment: shouldn't I get every messages sent to that user with that ?

Comment: that was a very reduced example, include a second where enforcing the second user as well

Comment: You could use query.whereKey("sender", equalTo: "user1") or something similar to that

Answer (score 1):

I believe the true answer lies in changing the structure of your model. What I suggest is to make a class called "Conversation" on parse. This class will have:

1. A member called "messages" (which is an array of all the messages sent/received in the conversation)
2. A member called "participants" - an array of strings of the participants' ids that are in the conversation (the ids can be their object id)

Then all you would have to do is query on class Conversation whereKey("participants", containedIn: ids) where "ids" is a [String] of the participants' object ids (or any id you wish).

This design is what Layer uses: https://layer.com/

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion ! should I put the messages as pointer ? if yes how do I do that ? and If no : how can I query the messages then ?

Comment: I create the class conversation but it is in a way where each time you contact a person you create a new conversation which is not exactly what I am searching for... Do you have a way to make the conversation reopen if there is already one ?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by your first question? As for your second question, you could just query for the conversation before making one and check if that query returns an object, if so then you know it exists and u dont have to make one else make a new one

Comment: If I create a conversation I believe I should put the messages in an array in order to get all of them in one shot, but how can I put those messages in an array an get all of their data (the creation date and the text) ? I believe that it should be a pointer right ? but how can I make like an array of pointer

Comment: also, how can I query the name of both the sender and the receiver ?

Answer (score 0):

I think parse is not appropriate for the chat app because chat needs to be realtime and simultaneous so I suggest [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) or [Pusher](http://pusher.com) both socket system has realtime update and they're built for chat apps.

On the other hand if you're insisting about the parse maybe you can use,

PFObject `+objectWithoutDataWithClassName:objectId:` method link below,

https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#/c:objc(cs)PFObject(cm)objectWithoutDataWithClassName:objectId:

Also found firebase sample chat app [here](https://github.com/firebase/firechat-ios).

Comment: is there a way to make my app with both of these (Parse and Firebase)  ? cause I don't really want to start over again with a different backend system